# Trouble starting simulation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: flow-project

I have no trouble training an RL agent to stabilize traffic on my Macbook pro, but when I attempt to train on Ubuntu 18.04, I receive the following issue:

```
Created LogSyncer for /u/isaac3/ray_results/stabilizing_i696/PPO_WaveAttenuationMergePOEnv-v0_0_2019-10-07_16-32-248tali0xs -> 
*** Aborted at 1570483944 (unix time) try "date -d @1570483944" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
*** SIGILL (@0x416aee) received by PID 5525 (TID 0x7fd497f05740) from PID 4287214; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fd4976d8890 (unknown)
    @           0x416aee plasma::PlasmaStore::SendNotifications()
    @           0x416d3a plasma::PlasmaStore::PushNotification()
    @           0x4190d1 plasma::PlasmaStore::SealObject()
    @           0x41a369 plasma::PlasmaStore::ProcessMessage()
    @           0x41b59f _ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFviEZN6plasma11PlasmaStore13ConnectClientEiEUliE_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_datai
    @           0x439357 aeProcessEvents
== Status ==
Using FIFO scheduling algorithm.
Resources requested: 3/3 CPUs, 0/0 GPUs
Memory usage on this node: 0.8/16.9 GB
Result logdir: /u/isaac3/ray_results/stabilizing_i696
RUNNING trials:
 - PPO_WaveAttenuationMergePOEnv-v0_0:  RUNNING
    @           0x43967b aeMain

    @           0x41f207 plasma::PlasmaStoreRunner::Start()
    @           0x4166d1 plasma::StartServer()
    @           0x413345 main
    @     0x7fd4969b7b97 __libc_start_main
    @           0x414701 (unknown)
```

It seems like an issue with a dependency, any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a Ray issue. Could you post your ray version and also try uninstalling and reinstalling Ray?

Comment: Had ray 0.6.1, but upgrading to 0.7.5 fixed the problem.

Comment: Yep! If you look at the environment.yml, we are up to Ray 0.7.3 and it's highly possible Ray 0.7.5 can be run with no issues. Glad it got fixed!